# Normal iOS Development on Jailbroken device

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it alright if I'm a registered iPhone developer with a Provisional License for a Jailbroken iOS device? I jailbroke after submitting for review, but its the same device I tested on. Will this cause any complications besides weird behavior? Just want to play around with it, probably will remove it soon. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. Jailbreaking **does not remove functionality,** only adds some. As for the "compilcations" or "weird behavior", you don't have to expect those either - the changes jailbreaking makes to the system does not directly affect the userland, let alone the AppStore apps (and those which are being tested).